# phpmyadmin does not show all records of table

Tags: mysql, datatable, phpmyadmin, record

I have a table in MySQL. Today, when I was checking the records, I found out that phpMyAdmin does not show all of its records!
This is what I have when I press the `>>` link to see the last page of records:

[image]

But when I query the table by the code below, I receive another result!

```
SELECT id FROM tbl_users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4;
```

[image]

Who knows what's the matter?

Comment: There's nothing the matter. If you don't define an order MySQL returns records in the order they appear in the table, which is not necessarily the order in which they were added. When you list them by `id` that defines the order, so you will get a consistent answer.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular, as I know, the default order for tables is based on ID in form of Ascending. So when you execute a query like `select * from mytable` you will fetch the from ID @1 to the last ID. However, I added `order by id` to the end of default phpMyAdmin select query, and anything did not changed.